# Efficient way to communicate/track healing between combat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, healing, online-roleplaying, player-communication

I'm looking for a specific, tried and true, method to spend less table time when my groups need to heal up between encounters.

My specific situation is online (Roll20) Pathfinder games, so Channel Energy, Wands of Cure (various) Wounds, and looted potions are the tools of the trade, but answers that are generically applicable are fine too.

If it matters, players generally track their own Hit Points via HeroLab or Mythweavers sheets and their first resource bars, which may or may not be visible to the party (but actual numbers are only known to each player).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is asking for in-game methods ("Can my PC just tell another PC how many hp needs healed?") or out-of-game methods ("What electronic method on this platform is best for communicating my PC's hp to the other players?"). Can you clarify?

Comment: Out of character. As is, there's a jumble of people listing off methods to heal and numbers without anyone being sure exactly how many resources were used by whom. It ends up taking as long to sort it as the combat that caused all the damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from Dale M's suggestion of using an average roll suggest that whoever has the wand simply says "I'm going to heal each one of you one at a time going around until you tell me to stop" that short and simple phrase will ensure everyone gets healed enough. That would, in the game world, be quite a long and complicated task but it's quick and simple to explain and it cuts through why they might want to stop being healed such as they are at max health, or as close to max health that they don't want to waste a charge. It's their choice and doesn't risk metagaming of revealing their HP.

Then they simply type into chat how many charges they use. So it would be something like :

- Aragorn: 2 charges
- Bianca: 2 charges
- Xavier: 1 charges
- Yorick: 5 charges

As you're discussing what to do next, whoever has the wand totals that up and sees how many charges/scrolls are used. In this case, -10 charges from your wand or number of scrolls. Alas, poor Yorick, he absorbed a lot of crits.

Only on the rare occasion where the caster sees they would run out of charges would you need to alter this routine slightly. I still say you follow the rule where everyone gets one charge at a time going around in a circle as anyone may be hit and take damage, everyone should equally benefit from being equally further away from 0HP. But work from the idea that everyone gets one charge at a time going around and modify from there so ask who will give up a charge.

It's easier to get any from a large group to agree to forgo healing than declare who must get healing and then try to coerce concessions from others.

Of course, wands and scrolls should be used up first as they are hard to use in combat or other difficult situations like if party is separated by falling. That should be a standard rule. Distribute healing potions as evenly amongst the party as you can, there is no particular priority as anyone may take damage. If a caster has the ability to use a healing wand or scrolls of healing in their position it is down to them and them alone to decide who gets their share of healing potions.

Yes, there may be some bickering, but you are starting from a position where most people have enough healing potions, after all the healer probably pays more attention to who takes more damage. Or they may deem they need to keep their share of potions for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4):

### Just use average numbers outside combat

A Cure Light Wounds wand (at 3rd level caster say) heals 1d8+3 per charge, call it 8 (or 7 if you're stingy) - over the course of 50 charges it will make 2/10ths of stuff all difference. Do this for everything.

Outside combat this is just inventory management: once healing resources become plentiful (as I assume is the case or else you wouldn't be having the problem) PCs heal until they are fully healed. Sure some breaks they roll poorly and need more resources, sometimes they roll well and need fewer: it all comes out in the wash. In combat, resources are spent one at a time and use up the action economy - there you roll.

This way the player's can simply determine how many resources they need and say "I use 3 charges from the CLW wand" or "3 CMW potions".

Comment: Small typo, you mixed CLW and CMW into one, it's either 1d8+1 or 2d8+3

Comment: @Ifusaso A wand requires a 3rd level caster to make so a CLW wand cures 1d8+3

Comment: Unless created by someone specific, wands are assumed to be made at the minimum level of the spell based on the rule that says you can create magic items at a lower CL than your actual CL by choice, to reduce costs.

Comment: A CL3 wand of Cure light wounds would cost 2250gp to heal a total of 375hp on average (6gp per HP) a Cl1 wand of same spell is 750gp to heal a total of 275hp on average (2.72gp per HP). Though, a CL1 wand of Infernal Healing works out to 1.5gp for every 1HP healed.

Comment: Three wands of CL1 CLW would be much more healing for your money than a single wand of CL3 CLW.

Comment: The economics of wand creation are rather beside the point of the answer

Answer (score 0):

I use this method in "table" games, but I think it would nicely work online too.

Make sure every players can easily have access to information about the group healing resources that are commonly used during breaks (around a table a sheet of paper do the trick, on roll20 you should be able to write that somewhere). The sheet can look like:

> wands of Cure Light Wounds: (1d8+1); 4*50 + 12 charges (Clericus)
>
> staff of Cure Moderate Wounds: (2d8+8); 10 charges (Horaklion)
>
> wand of Infernal Healing: (10); 37 charges (Sorchorror)

I don't usually take into account Channel or spells that are supposed to be used in combat, nor potions that anyone can choose to drink or not by himself. This can of course work differently and it is ultimately up to your group to decide which resource is to be used as default healing.

Let's say after a fight everyone is more or less hurt. There are many HP to heal but also many wand charges. Clericus can say "I distribute heals with the wand until everyone is alright". Everyone rolls the d8s for the wand and take account of how many charges are spent, then they can note it on the group common healing resources sheet. In a "table" game there is often one player taking track of all the spent charges for all the others but I don't recommend it online as it is easy to just don't take correctly into account four people telling you different numbers more-or-less at the same time. For your online game I recommend you to stick with the note everyone can edit, if possible, or at least privilegiate the written chat over the vocal one.

This is particularly efficient if some character has many missing HP and would require dozens of charges to get healed. With this system the player can roll for himself and stop when the PC is ok, while the other are planning for the next fight or doing anything more interesting than watching someone repeatedly rolling dice. Just consider that while the player is rolling its dice he is being healed and can't really pay attention to the discussions.

This doesn't work if the group is stranded on healing resources, but in that case how to spend the remaining charges becomes suddenly a more interesting problem that is worth spending a bit of table time on it.

Comment: The question was about an online game. Could you edit your answer to specify why your suggestion cannot be applied in online games? As Roll20 has a chat window where each player can clearly state number of charges used.

Comment: @TREB: I think it can with a few adjustments, but I haven't tried it in online game conditions, thus the first sentence of my answer: "I use this method in "table" games, but I think it would nicely work online too."

Comment: 4th paragraph, 5th line down, you say "I don't recommend it online". It isn't clear what you're saying or your reasoning.

Comment: In this sentence I am talking about having one person who tracks all the healing resources. Around a physical table it can be handy as it means you don't have to pass the paper sheet around, but online it would not be that great. I forgot about the chat window, it sure would be more handy than just speaking.